# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeClass' of undefined jQuery easydropdown

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've seen this question has been asked a few times but nothing has been able to help.

On my cshtml file I have the following:

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
    @Html.Raw(SelectListHelper.CreateDropDownList("ddlStateCode", Application.DataCache.GetStatesAsLookup()))
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <select class="dropdown" id="ddlContactList"></select>
</div>
```

The Razor dropdown renders a select tag just the same as ddlContactList, aside from the ID.

ddlContactList gets populated via AJAX.

ddlStateCode throws the error when I click on it, and ddlContactList works just fine.

We are including the following scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jsrender.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/globalize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/ej.widgets.all-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/App/image-changer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/App/nav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/App/popup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/App/scrollbar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/App/show_hide.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/App/jqueryExtensions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/App/helper_functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/App/ConfirmPopup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/App/global_error_handlers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.easydropdown.js"></script>
```

The problem occurs in jQuery.easydropdown.js on the below method:

```
close: function(){
    var self = this;
    self.$container.removeClass('open'); // error happens here
    self.$scrollWrapper.css('height','0px');
    self.focusIndex = self.selected.index;
    self.query = '';
    self.down = false;
},
```

I don't think the jQuery UI file and the jQuery file versions need to match but I can't find matching versions to try. Any ideas?

Comment: `var self = this;` - this really smells weird here, as there's no need for caching `this` object within `close()`. Add `console.log(self)` right at the top of this method; what does it show?

Comment: Try `console.log(self)` and check if `self` contains `$container` or not!

Comment: @raina77ow it shows 'undefined' - this was in the jQuery file so I'm not exactly sure what is happening... This was working fine until we added in this jquery.easydropdown.js

Comment: Actually - `var self = this;` `console.log(self);` shows `EasyDropDown` that contains `$container`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EasyDropDown breaks on a selectlist that is empty on page load. Removing the encapsulating function in the javascript file and firing the instantiate method after the AJAX call fixes it.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem.I have an empty select list where the options are created using a loop-it is a loop that creates timestamps. The plugin seems to be ineffective when I create the options with the loop...take a look at the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlehunt/j54e7/   what should I do to fix the issue?Try the above solution? –  Dimitris Papageorgiou 6 mins ago